# MagicalRecord iCloud backup

Tags: ios5, core-data, icloud, xcode4.5, magicalrecord

I use MagicalRecord for data store (CoreData).I want use for data backup iCloud but I don't know how to read and write data to iCloud with using MagicalRecord. Anybody know how to use iCloud backup with using MagicalRecord? Any help will be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog series very helpful to figure out how to set up a project for iCloud with Core Data:
http://mentalfaculty.tumblr.com/post/23163747823/under-the-sheets-with-icloud-and-core-data-the-basics

Then, you set up MagicalRecord to use an iCloud Core Data store with this line in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"xxxxxxxxxx.com.companyname.appname" localStoreNamed:@"local_data_store_name"];
```

Replacing xxxxxxxx with the App ID from iTunes Connect, companyname with your iTunes Connect Company name, and appname with the name of your app. The local_data_store_name can be whatever you want.

Also, make sure you download and install the new Profile you will be creating to match your App ID. Xcode for me did not do it automatically. I also had to update my device to the current latest OS update, for iCloud to work correctly for testing.